# AQL query to return classifier

Tags: artifactory, artifactory-query-lang

I'm using `AQL` query to find artifacts by build name and number and I need to get the `classifier` tag in the response :

```
items.find( 
      {"name":{"$match":"*.jar"}},
      {"name":{"$nmatch":"*-sources.jar"}},
      {"name":{"$nmatch":"*-javadoc.jar"}},
      {"artifact.module.build.name":MY_BUILD_NAME},
      {"artifact.module.build.number":MY_BUILD_NUMBER}
)
.include("repo","path","name","artifact.module.name","WHAT SHOULD BE HERE TO GET THE classifier")
```

What is the field name to get the `classifier` back ?

Thanks

Comment: you could upload your artifacts including `classifier` as a property, this would let you access it in AQL.

Comment: Thanks, @FlorianCastellane, I suppose it will look like `items.find({"name":{{"$nmatch":"*-myClassifier.jar"}}})` ?

Comment: something like `items.find({"artifact.item.@classifier":"myClassifierValue"})` is simple enough. NB: Just writing `items.find({"key":"value"})` for a match is also possible, the `$nmatch` is not necessary for simple queries.

Answer (score 1):

The Maven classifier is not part of the AQL data model.
You can find a list of all the entities and fields [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+Query+Language#ArtifactoryQueryLanguage-EntitiesandFields).
The best way I can think of for getting the classifier would be parsing the artifact name.